# Only get field names from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, recordset

Right now when I run the following query `SELECT * FROM table` I get the following response

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(36) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "31764"
    ["id"]=>
    string(5) "31764"
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

As you can see I am getting 2 of the same data ("0" and "id"). Is there any way I can only get "id" and not "0"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation of [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), the second argument allows you to specify what kind of array to return:

> The type of array that is to be fetched. It's a constant and can take the following values: MYSQL_ASSOC, MYSQL_NUM, and MYSQL_BOTH.

Or you could just use [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).

Answer (score 0):

you can write the sql just like :
SELECT 'id' FROM table 
it wil just return